# Rails + Capybara: "has_select(..., options:...) failing, even though select exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 4, Cucumber, Capybara. For this particular scenario, I am using the @javascript tag, which uses the Selenium driver.

In my test, I am testing a select dropdown that uses jQuery + ajax. Here are the steps: a user goes onto the form page, then clicks on the dropdown to expand it, and clicks the "Create a new color..." option. When that is selected, a text field appears and the person can type in a color name. When they press enter, that color is created and the select drop down is reloaded to include that new color in the options.

step definitions:

```
When(/^I create a new color named "(.*?)"$/) do |color_name|
  find("option[id='new_color_option']").click
  fill_in("color[name]", with: color_name)
  find(:id, 'new_color_text_field').native.send_keys(:enter)
end

Then(/^"(.*?)" should be on the color list$/) do |color_name|
  expect(page).to have_select("color", options: [color_name])
end
```

And it fails with this:

```
Then "Blue" should be on the color list       # features/step_definitions/cms/products_steps.rb:175
  expected to find select box "color" but there were no matches. Also found "Blue Create a new color...", which matched the selector but not all filters. (Capybara::ExpectationNotMet)
  ./features/step_definitions/cms/products_steps.rb:177:in `/^"(.*?)" should be on the color list$/'
  features/cms/products.feature:53:in `Then "Blue" should be on the color list'
```

The problem is that it's failing to find my select dropdown. I am staring at the driver open the browser and even added a `sleep 20` inbetween so that I could inspect the HTML.

Before adding a color:

```
    <select class="colors" name="color">

        <option id="new_color_option" value="">

            Create a new color...

        </option>

    </select>
```

After adding a color:

```
    <select class="colors" name="color">

        <option value="1" selected="selected">

            Blue

        </option>
        <option id="new_color_option" value="">

            Create a new color...

        </option>

    </select>
```

Why is it that it can't find my select dropdown?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to change

```
expect(page).to have_select("color", options: [color_name])
```

to use `with_options` instead of `options`.

```
expect(page).to have_select("color", with_options: [color_name])
```

`options` does an exact match of all options where `with_options` is a partial match.

Comment: Wow nice. This is exactly what I was looking for actually

Answer (score 1):

The `has_select?` method is looking for a `<select/>` with *exactly* the options you specify. Try this:

```
expect(page).to have_select("color", options: [color_name, "Create a new color..."])
```

The error message `which matched the selector but not all filters` is a clue, since it’s finding the element, but the filters (`options` in this case) are not matching.