# How do you refute the presence of an option with Capybara's has_select?

Tags: testing, capybara

Consider that you have a select list with just the following option:

```
<option>Second Fake Option</option>
```

And you'd like to assert that the select list does *not* contain an option with the text "Fake Option":

```
<option>Fake Option</option>
```

When one refutes this like so:

```
refute has_select?('list_id',
  with_options: ['Fake Option'])
```

The test fails. It seems that Capybara is successfully *partially* matching the *text* `Fake Option` against the text `Second Fake Option`. Even further, the following also fails:

```
refute has_select?('select_id',
  with_options: [''])
```

Yet the following passes:

```
refute has_select?('select_id',
  with_options: ['BORK'])
```

The documentation for `with_options:` and `options:` describes the behavior regarding the *list* of options we're trying to match, but does not speak to this behavior of partially matching the text itself. [Other questions here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23814496/rails-capybara-has-select-options-failing-even-though-select-exis) refer to the same documented behavior... but don't address refuting or the matching of the options' text.

While I could `assert` the opposite behavior with `options:`, like this:

```
assert has_select?('select_id',
  options: ['Second Fake Option'])
```

This can be a pain when you have a long select list and want to refute the presence of one particular option in the list.

How does one properly *refute* the presence of a specific option in a select list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial text matching is the default behavior but can be overridden with the :exact option.  Also rather than refuting a predicate, you should be calling `refute_select` -- the error messages will be much better

```
refute_select('select_id', with_options: ['Fake Option'], exact: true)
```

Note: this would also pass if there was no 'select_id' select element on the page, which may not be what you want. If you want to verify the select does exist but that it doesn't have a specific option then something like

```
select = find_field('select_id')
refute_selector(select, :option, 'Fake Option', exact:  true)
```

may be what you want, which could also be done with matches as

```
select = find_select('select_id')
refute_matches_selector(select, :select, with_options['Fake Option'], exact: true)
```

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Walpole, I had forgotten about `refute_select`!. However, this first approach doesn't work. First, `exact: true` doesn't seem to have the intended effect. For example, `refute_select('select_id', with_options: ['Fake Option']` and `refute_select('select_id', with_options: ['Fake Option'], exact: true` both fail. The failure output is `expected not to find visible select box "select_id" that is not disabled with at least options ["Fake Option"], found 1 match: "Choose... Second Fake Option"`.

Comment: @ybakos What version of Capybara are you using?

Comment: Too funny, I was just going to write. "Ok Thomas, I'm the dumbass running an outdated version of Capybara." In version 3.15, everything behaves as expected. Thanks again. `refute_select` with `exact: true` does indeed work.

Comment: @ybakos I assume you mean 3.10 - since that's the latest (3.10.1 will be in a few minutes) - but glad to hear it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can refute the presence of the option directly via

```rb
assert_no_selector("option[value='Fake Option']", visible: :all)
```

Note `visible: :all` which will still match / refute match if the select's options are hidden.